# Get recipient number in Android Message app

Tags: android, android-intent

We're doing an app, where the user can send a MMS, and we would like to be able to extract the phone number from the current SMS/MMS (if one is open) and reapply it, so we don't delete the recipient when inserting the image...

So is there any way for us to access this info, so we can set it with:

picMessageIntent.putExtra("address", new String("here we want the number"));

Comment: What do you mean by "current SMS/MMS (if one is open)"? Open in what, exactly?

Comment: "Open" as in currently in focus... Our product is a keyboard... So if the user has the Message app open and a recipient is already entered, when we currently attach the image, the recipient will also be deleted and set to empty... But we would like to get the recipient and add him/her again in our intent

Comment: You mean, the user opens their messaging app, enters a recipient, uses your keyboard to select an image, and then your keyboard fires an Intent to open the messaging app again? Seems kind of circuitous. Anyway, it might be possible with an `AccessibilityService`, but you never know which messaging app a user is going to choose to use.

Comment: The issue is, we have to insert an image as an MMS... And I haven't found a solution that can insert an image without using startActivity with Intent.EXTRA_STREAM...

Comment: Yeah, unless you want to include MMS functionality directly in your app, that's about the only way to do it. If I were doing what you are, though, I'd probably include an Activity or Dialog in the app itself in which the user could both enter the recipient, and select the image, and then have it fire the Intent to open the messaging app with all the necessary data attached.

Comment: Yeah, that could be another approach... We'll have a talk with our client and see what they would prefer...